# Computing invariant subspaces of $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra

In general, how does one compute all invariant subspaces for a $3 \times 3$ real matrix $T$?

Here are a couple of facts I've been able to establish:

1. $\{ 0 \}$ is the only 0-dimensional invariant subspace; $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the only 3-dimensional invariant subspace
2. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace#Uni-dimensional_invariant_subspace), I see that all 1-dimensional invariant subspaces are generated by the eigenvectors of $T$.

   - This leaves only the 2-dimensional invariant subspaces left to find
3. In general, if $A, B$ are invariant subspaces of $T$, then $A \oplus B$ is an invariant subspace

   - To confirm: is this point indeed correct?

Is the combination of the second and third facts enough to compute all of the 2-dimensional invariant subspaces (and thus answering my question)? I'm also afraid that the above algorithm might only work for diagonalizable matrices?

Thanks.

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407217/determine-invariant-subspaces) [are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704842/invariant-subspaces-using-matrix-of-linear-operator) [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243297/finding-invariant-subspaces) [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631804/invariant-subspaces-linear-algebra-problem) questions, which others might find useful; but none fully answer my question I feel.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit as part of the direct sum being a subspace, the direct sum $A\oplus B$ of invariant subspaces $A$ and $B$ is an invariant subspace as long as $A\cap B=\{0\}$. Assuming that you have this condition, the properties of a linear transformation will give you the result in your third point:

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under a linear transformation $T$ with $A\cap B=\{0\}$. So for $u\in A$ and $v\in B$, $Tu\in A$ and $Tv\in B$. Then $$T(u+v)=Tu+Tv\in A\oplus B.$$

This will not be enough to calculate all invariant subspaces. Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $Te_1=e_2$, $Te_2=-e_1$, and $Te_3=e_3$ (where $e_i$ is the standard $i$'th basis vector. Then $\mathbb{R}e_1\oplus\mathbb{R}e_2$ is invariant under $T$ but does not have any non-trivial invariant subspaces.

For a more extensive study of invariant subspaces explore the Jordan Canonical Form.